# Moving a point of a line with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I have a line with a start and end point.
I need to move the initial point of a variable distance but always following the direction of the line.

[image]

If there any Node that allows you to do that easily?

Thanks for your help ;)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the positions of the endpoints you can create a new vector and move the point in that direction like this:
[image: Subtracting a positional vector gives us with a direction we can scale]

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you :)